# Django: If I call is_valid() on a form do I still have to clean the data in forms.py?

Tags: django, forms, validation

If I call `is_valid()` on a form do I still have to clean the data in forms.py? I feel like it is redundant. I know that `is_valid()` is suppose run `clean()` automatically, so why would the framework let the user use the `clean()` function in forms.py?

**forms.py**

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
my_validator = RegexValidator("\d{6}\-\d{2}", "CAPA format needs to be ######-##.")

class IncidentSearchForm(forms.Form):

    id = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    user_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(User.objects.all(), required=False) 
    capa = forms.CharField(
        label="CAPA",
        required=False,
        validators=[my_validator]
        )

    def search(self):

        id = self.cleaned_data.get('id')
        user_id = self.cleaned_data.get('user_id')
        capa = self.cleaned_data.get('capa', None)

        if id is not None:
            query = query.filter(id=id))
        if user_id is not None:
            query = query.filter(user_id=user_id)
        if capa is not '':
            query = query.filter(capa=capa)

        return(query)
```

**view.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):

    template = "index.html"
    form = IncidentSearchForm(request.GET) # or None
    incident_list = None

    if form.is_valid():
        incident_list = form.search()
        context = { "form": form,                       
                    "incident_list": incident_list}
        return render(request, template, context)

    else:
        # form is empty show all OPEN incidents
        form = IncidentSearchForm()
        incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(open = 'True').order_by('-incident_date_time_reported')
        context = { "form": form,
                    "incident_list": incident_list}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: You're not required to call clean on a form. Like you said, it does it when you call .is_valid(). You call/override clean if you want to preform any custom validations

Comment: okay, so did I do anything unnecessarily or redundant in the code above? I keep feeling like `self.cleaned_data.get` is redundant because I call `is_valid()` in views.py. I'm starting to get it I think. I would override the clean for `capa`

Comment: `self.cleaned_data.get` gets the results after is_valid has called `clean`.

Answer (score 1):

[`is_valid()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L165) checks the form's `errors` property which (assuming it hasn't already been run) calls [`full_clean()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L366) which calls [`_clean_form()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L406) which calls `clean()` so there is no need to call the method directly.

> keep feeling like self.cleaned_data.get is redundant because I call is_valid() in views.py

I'm not 100% sure on your objection, but note that `cleaned_data` will be empty unless `clean()` completes successfully, so your `search` function won't work properly without the check. You are correct that you shouldn't need to use `get` there for any required fields, but since you don't have required fields it's still a better bet.